# How to create auto vote script using `expect`?

Tags: expect

I'd like to test auto-vote protection on my site (not published yet).

I've found [Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) program, but I can't get it working with telnet http.

Comment: Using it in a telnet / command line way is not preferred. Expect is a perl module, and as such you can use it together with LWP::Simple and create a very simple web client.

Comment: @Tommy, I don't understand your comment: Expect is not merely a perl module: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect

Comment: @glennjackman : Perhaps I should have sais 'Expect is a perl module as well'. You can find expect bindings to most popular programming languages. And thus, create your very own (simple) http client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the "curl" command line tool to do this. I'm presuming that you have a form submission, in which a field `vote` can choose `A`, `B`, or `C`, for example:

```
curl -F vote=A http://example.com/submitvote/
```

or, if there were a name field to go with it, for example:

```
curl -F vote=C -F name="my name" http://example.com/submitvote/
```